# Time on Vue.JS Refreshing automatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I intend to show this clock on Vue. This clock automatically refreshes the time but how do I convert this code?

Is there an easy way to convert this to Vue? Vue doesn't have (`document.getElementBy`...)

```js
function time () {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}
var timeInterval = setInterval(time, 1000); // recalls the function every 1000 ms

<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Please read documentation first :) 
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#declarative-rendering

Comment: I suggest reading the vue documentation and getting familiar with how vue operates before posting here as this is a pretty entry level task

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code in a Vue 3 style :

```
<template>
   <h1>Hello World {{ time }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    var time = ref()
    setInterval(() => {
      time.value = new Date().toString('hh:mm:ss tt')
    }, 1000)

    return { time }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `document.getElementById`, it can also be done using `refs` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  mounted() {
    var timeInterval = setInterval(this.time, 1000);
  },
  methods: {
    time: function() {
      this.$refs.time.innerHTML = new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref="time"></div>
</div>
```

Or by updating a `data` attribute as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() { return { time: "" } },
  mounted() { 
    var timeInterval = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1000);
  },
  methods: {
    updateTime: function() {
      this.time = new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{time}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a digital clock in Vue Js that periodically changes its value in real time using the setInterval() method. See an example below:

```js
const {ref, createApp} = Vue

createApp({
    setup() {
        //define variable date using reactivity API
        const date = ref(new Date())
        //change date value periodically using setInterval() method
        setInterval(() => {
            date.value = new Date()
        }, 1000)

        return {
            date
        }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.1/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<!-- display a digital clock with the format hour:minute:second to the browser -->
      <h3> {{date.getHours()}}:{{date.getMinutes()}}:{{date.getSeconds()}}</h3>
</div>
```

The result in the browser will look like this: **21:31:05**